# Connection between elliptic integrals and theta functions

Tags: calculus, elliptic-integrals, theta-functions

I have read about connections between elliptic integrals and their connections to the Jacobi theta functions, like $\theta_3^2(q) = \frac{2}{\pi}K(k)$, where $q=e^{-\pi\frac{K’(k)}{K(k)}}$, but how would you prove these identities as I have found little about their proofs and have no idea how to go about it.

Comment: The connection discovered by Jacobi between elliptic functions and quotients of $\vartheta$ functions is a great accomplishment. It is explained in a very nice way on an historical standpoint in this book (its first hundred pages can be consulted [here]())
"Hidden Harmony—Geometric Fantasies,  The Rise of Complex Function Theory. (Springer editor) Authors : **Bottazzini**, Umberto and **Gray**, Jeremy.

Comment: This can be done using Arithmetic-geometric means and explained in [this](https://paramanands.blogspot.com/2010/10/the-magic-of-theta-functions.html?m=0) and the [following](https://paramanands.blogspot.com/2010/10/the-magic-of-theta-functions-contd.html?m=0) post.

Comment: Another approach by Ramanujan is to study the properties of the related hypergeometric functions and in particular show that $F(x) /x\to 1/16$ as $x\to 0^+$ where $F(x) =\exp\left(-\pi\frac{{} _2F_1(\tfrac{1}{2},\tfrac{1}{2};1;1-x) } {{} _2F_1(\tfrac{1}{2},\tfrac{1}{2};1;x) } \right) $

Comment: Ramanujan's approach is discussed in [this](https://paramanands.blogspot.com/2011/12/elementary-approach-to-modular-equations-ramanujan-theory-2.html?m=0) and the [following](https://paramanands.blogspot.com/2011/12/elementary-approach-to-modular-equations-ramanujan-theory-3.html?m=0) post.